# Laravel sin utilizar los Models?

Tags: base-de-datos, laravel-5, controller, model, model-view-controller

Les quería hacer la siguiente consulta respecto al modo de trabajo de Laravel 5.5.

¿Es posible trabajar o desarrollar un proyecto con Laravel sin usar los Modelos,  Es decir, solo utilizando los controladores para obtener y enviar los datos a las vistas  (usando Query Builder) .?

PD: Es en base a un proyecto con una base de datos existente y que se modifica constantemente.

De ante mano muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Es posible, pero personalmente no le sacas todo el partido a Laravel, podrías probar con CodeIgniter si no te interesa Eloquent y sólo te interesa Query Builder.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, en estos momento me encuentro trabajando en un proyecto utilizando esa vía, pero de todas maneras intentaré utilizar los Modelos en una próxima ocasión (es el primer framework con el que trabajo ).  Saludos!!